# React | How to render only 1 object from an array that is part of a nested object

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, maps

I have this data structure:

```js
const data = [
 {
   title: 'title',
   description: 'description'
   images: [
    { mainImg: 'url' },
    { img1: 'url' },
    { img2: 'url' },
    { img3: 'url' },
  ],
 },
 ...
]
```

My question is, how can I render only the mainImg separated from the others? And how can I render the other images without the mainImg.

What I've tied so far is to map through the `images` like this: (I did mapped through data before)

```js
{data.images.map((img, index) => (
  <img
    key={`image${index}`}
    src={img.mainImg}
    className={styles.mainImg}
  />
 ))
}
```

This worked, but the issue is that I map through all the images and when I open the consoles, all the images are rendered but they are not visible because they don't have the `src` tag. (I think).

Simply trying to use `data.images.mainImg` as the `src` value doesn't render anything, and also does not throw any errors.

Also, I have an issue trying to render all the other images except the mainImg. This is what I've tried but I get lost and I don't know what the `src` value should be.

```js
{data.images
  .filter((img) => img.mainImg != project.images.mainImg)
  .map((img, index) => (
    <img src={img} />
 ))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `hasOwnProperty` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

```
data.images.map((e, i) => {
  if (e.hasOwnProperty('mainImg')) {
    // Do something with mainImg
  }
  //Do something with the others
})
```

A JSfiddle with example : https://jsfiddle.net/RyanZee/hu189jxd/12/

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have a `mainImg` at index 0? If so you can use

```
const [firstImg, ...imgs] = data.images;
return (
  <>
    <img src={firstImg.mainImg} ... />
    { imgs.map((img, index) => <img src={img[`img${index + 1}`]} /> }
  </>
)
```

Comment: It won't be always at the same index